# Throw std::wstring as exception

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following code:

```
void ThrowAnException()
{
    // This calls catch (LPCWSTR e):
    //throw(L"This is my exception.");

    std::wstring exception = L"This is my exception.";
    throw(exception);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        ThrowAnException();
    }
    catch (LPCWSTR e) { MessageBoxW(nullptr, e, L"User Exception (LPCWSTR)", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); }
    catch (...) { MessageBoxA(nullptr, "No details available", "Unknown Exception", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the first `throw` caught by the `LPCWSTR` (pointer to constant string), and the second `throw` is not?
What should I catch to get the second `throw`?

Thank you.

Comment: To catch the 2nd `throw` you can add `catch (std::wstring const & e) {...}`.

Comment: A `std::wstring` object is a `std:wstring` object. There's no natural conversion available to `const wchar_t *`  (which is what `LPCWSTR` really is).

Comment: The two throws are different types so need different catches

Comment: Throwing something what do not inherit `std::exception` is a bad practice. https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e14-use-purpose-designed-user-defined-types-as-exceptions-not-built-in-types Other languages are enforcing some base class for types which can be thrown.

Comment: As a side note, there is absolutely no advantage in using the macro `LPCWSTR` instead of `const wchar_t*`. All it does is hide the real type. (There was a **very small** advantage in the early 1990s, but MS has never cared to update their documentation).

Comment: @MarekR the link you mentiond above does not says that _"Throwing something what do not inherit std::exception is a bad practice"_. It even gives an example of throwing `MyCustomError` which does not derive from `std::exception`. The recommendation is to avoid throwing build-in types that convey little information. I can see that `std::string` can be considered to fall in this category, but it could be also argued the opposite.

Comment: @wohlstad yes link I provided not state this explicitly, but `std::string` is not type which is `purpose-designed` or `user-defined`.

Comment: @MarekR Agree with that, and updated my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::wstring` is not a `LPCWSTR` (which is actually a `const wchar_t *`), and therefore your current `catch` does not cover it.

In order to do it, you can add a proper `catch` phrase accepting a `const std::wstring &`:

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

void ThrowAnException()
{
    std::wstring exception = L"This is my exception.";
    throw(exception);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        ThrowAnException();
    }
    catch (LPCWSTR e)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, e, L"User Exception (LPCWSTR)", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    //-----vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-
    catch (const std::wstring & e)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, e.c_str(), L"User Exception (wstring)", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    catch (...) 
    { 
        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "No details available", "Unknown Exception", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
    }
}
```

Note that `std::wstring` does have a method for getting a `const wchat *` from it - `c_str()`, which is what I used for printing the content of it in the MessageBox.

---

Edit:
As @MarekR commented above, according to the [Cpp Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e14-use-purpose-designed-user-defined-types-as-exceptions-not-built-in-types), it is recommended to use **purpose-designed user-defined types** for throwing, and neither `LPCWSTR` nor `std::wstring` are such types.
Therefore you should consider to avoid them. Instead you can define your own exception types, possibly derived from `std::exception`.